# Want to disable a cell from editing if the other cell has a certain value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to disable a cell if another call contains certain values, i have written the below piece of code but it is throwing me an error

> "Wrong number of argument or invalid property assignment".

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Dim projworkbook As Workbook
    Dim page1 As Worksheet

    Set projworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set page1 = projworkbook.Worksheets("Project_Creation")

    If Me.ComboBox1.Text = "Extention" Then
        Me.ComboBox2.Visible = True else
        page1.Range("B5").AllowEdit = False '-> I am getting error here
    end if
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `.AllowEdit` is read only, so you cannot set it to `False`.

Instead use `.Locked = True` to lock a range, or accordingly `.Locked = False` to unlock a range.

Note that the worksheet needs to be protected so that this property is used. By default all ranges are marked as `.Locked = True` so if you protect a sheet everything gets locked. So you probably need to unlock the ranges you don't want to be locked when you protect the sheet.

Comment: Hi, 
The worksheet is protected and as you suggested i have made .Locked = False.
When i did this i got an error 1004:Unable to set the locked property of the range class

Comment: You need to unprotect the sheet first then change the locked state and then re-protect the sheet.